# Fragments inside ViewPager is not refreshing contents or its views

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-listview

MainActivity.java

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

    Toolbar toolbar;
    ViewPager pager;
    ViewPagerAdapter adapter;
    SlidingTabLayout tabs;
    private ArrayList<String> mLanguagesArray = null;
    int Numboftabs;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    if (savedInstanceState == null) {
        Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
        if (extras != null) {
            mLanguagesArray = new ArrayList<String>();
            mLanguagesArray.addAll(extras.getStringArrayList("languages"));
            Numboftabs = mLanguagesArray.size();
        } 
    }

        toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.tool_bar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        getSupportActionBar().setIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher);

        adapter = new ViewPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager(),
                mLanguagesArray, Numboftabs, MainActivity.this);

        pager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
        pager.setAdapter(adapter);

        // Assiging the Sliding Tab Layout View
        tabs = (SlidingTabLayout) findViewById(R.id.tabs);

        tabs.setViewPager(pager);
        tabs.setOnPageChangeListener(new ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int arg0) {
            }

            @Override
            public void onPageScrolled(int arg0, float arg1, int arg2) {
            }

            @Override
            public void onPageSelected(int arg0) {
                refreshListInFragment(arg0);
            }
        });
    }
    protected void refreshListInFragment(int position) {
        String currentLanguage = mLanguagesArray.get(position);
        FragmentManager fm = getSupportFragmentManager();
        ListviewFragment fragment = (ListviewFragment) fm
                .findFragmentById(R.id.pager);
        fragment.loadListview(currentLanguage);
    }
}
```

ViewPagerAdapter.java

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import android.content.Context;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentStatePagerAdapter;

public class ViewPagerAdapter extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter {
    ArrayList<String> Titles;
    int NumbOfTabs;
    Context mContext;

    public ViewPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm,
            ArrayList<String> mLanguagesArray, int mNumbOfTabsumb,
            Context context) {
        super(fm);
        Titles = new ArrayList<String>();
        this.Titles = mLanguagesArray;
        this.NumbOfTabs = mNumbOfTabsumb;
        this.mContext = context;

    }
    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        ListviewFragment listfragment = new ListviewFragment(mContext);
        return listfragment;
    }

    @Override
    public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
        return Titles.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return NumbOfTabs;
    }
}
```

ListviewFragment.java

```
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.ProgressBar;

public class ListviewFragment extends Fragment {
    ProgressBar progressbar;
    ListView list;
    ArrayList<RStore> mRstoreList = null;
    RadioListAdapter adapter;
    Context mContext;
    Button tryagain;
    String mCurrentLanguage = null;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.listviewfragment, container, false);
        progressbar = (ProgressBar) v.findViewById(R.id.progressbar);
        list = (ListView) v.findViewById(R.id.listview);
        if (ListviewFragment.this.isMenuVisible()) {
            if (mRstoreList == null) {
                loadListview("English");
            }
        }
        return v;
    }

    public void loadListview(final String currentlanguage) {
        this.mCurrentLanguage = currentlanguage;
        mRstoreList = new ArrayList<RStore>();
        new AsyncTask<Void, Void, String>() {
            private String jsonStr;
            @Override
            protected void onPreExecute() {
                list.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                progressbar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                tryagain.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                super.onPreExecute();
            }
            @Override
            protected String doInBackground(Void... arg0) {
                try {
                    String URL = ServiceUrls.MUSIC_PHP;
                    CustomHttpClient sh = new CustomHttpClient();
                    JSONObject jsonobjpost = new JSONObject();
                    jsonobjpost.put("languages", currentlanguage);
                    jsonStr = sh.makeServiceCall(URL, CustomHttpClient.POST,
                            jsonobjpost.toString());
                    System.out.println("MUSIC_PHP_Response " + jsonStr);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                return jsonStr;
            }

            @Override
            protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
                if (result == null || result.trim().equalsIgnoreCase("null")
                        || result.trim().equalsIgnoreCase("")) {
                    progressbar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    super.onPostExecute(result);
                    return;
                }
                try {
                    String DUMMYJASON = result.toString();
                    JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(DUMMYJASON);
                    JSONArray jsonArray = jsonObject.getJSONArray("Language");
                    for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {
                        JSONObject obj = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
                        String id = obj.getString("id");
                        String language = obj.getString("language");
                        String tittle = obj.getString("Tittle");
                        String link = obj.getString("link");
                        RStore storecon = new RStore();
                        storecon.setId(id);
                        storecon.setLanguage(language);
                        storecon.setTitle(tittle);
                        storecon.setLink(link);
                        mRstoreList.add(storecon);
                    }
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

                adapter = new RadioListAdapter(mContext, mRstoreList);
                list.setAdapter(adapter);
                list.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                progressbar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                super.onPostExecute(result);
            }
        }.executeOnExecutor(AsyncTask.THREAD_POOL_EXECUTOR);
    }
    public ListviewFragment(Context context) {
        this.mContext = context;
    }
}
```

I'm creating number of fragments dynamically using one fragment class called `ListviewFragment` and setting it as view page adapter. ListviewFragment contains listview which is populated dynamically from service. With my code everything is working fine the only problem is, sometimes the datas inside the fragments are not refreshing or updating with new values. In my case the listview is showing the previously loaded data but in background the service is called and the listview Adapter is updated but the updated listview is not showing in the fragment. Please see my code, and correct me if i made any mistake..Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of calling a method with (currentLanguage) as a parameter in fragment from activity using findFragmentById, I've just passed (currentLanguage) as bundle in ViewPagerAdapter getItem() method and in ListviewFragment class onCreateView i got (currentlanguage) value using getArguments and passed it to (loadListview) method. Now everything works fine and clean.

ViewPagerAdapter.java

```
@Override
public Fragment getItem(int position) {
    Bundle args = new Bundle();
    args.putString("language", Titles.get(position));
    ListviewFragment f = new ListviewFragment(mContext);
    f.setArguments(args);
    return f;
}
```

ListviewFragment.java

```
private void getarugs() {
    Bundle args = getArguments();
    mCurrentLanguage = args.getString("language");
    loadListview(mCurrentLanguage);
}
```